# How to use semantic tests in the listeners with ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

I would like to avoid to use programming in the PARSER grammar file and use a semantic check in the listener. Can I do it ? How to do it ? Do I throw an exception ? Call a method of the parser ?

Thank you.

Edit : I said lexer, it's a mistake. I mean PARSER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use `Recognizer#addErrorListener(ANTLRErrorListener)` to capture semantic and other errors -- the parser extends `Recognizer`.

Check for the existence of captured errors after the parser runs to decide whether/how to continue.

To affect how the parser handles errors, use `Parser#setErrorHandler(ANTLRErrorStrategy)`.  The runtime includes a `BailErrorStrategy` that can be used to stop the parser when a syntactic error is encountered.

Comment: You probably mean "... stop the parser when a syntactic error is encountered". The parser cannot understand semantic.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's perfect for me, and clean for the grammar.